# Syntax React single-quote/double-quote <Link to=></Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've used the following code with the usual quotes ' ' or " ".

```
 <Link to={'/view/${post.code}'}>
```

In the URL it was passing /view/$%7B**post.code**%7D rather than the item ID which not what i wanted

Then using the other single-quote, the URL was returning the correct item ID such as /view/itemID

```
<Link to={`/view/${post.code}`}>
```

how comes the usual single-quote or double-quote did not work and i had to use the "other" quotes where the code is exactly the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the "other" quotes aka back tick is for template literals which allows embedded expressions.

More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Whatever is inside ${} will be interpolated.

E.g.

```
var name = "World";
console.log(`Hello ${name}`); \\ will be evaluated to "Hello World";
```

In your case it remained "/view/${post.code}" when you used single or double quotes and the URL was encoded hence brackets became %7B & %7D and post.code remained un-interpolated.

Answer (score 1):

because when you use the backtick (``) and inside it you have the ${name_of_variable}  this is called *template literal* check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)